# Async and Visual Studio failure handling

Tags: .net, visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx):

> If the method that the async keyword modifies doesn't contain an await
>   expression or statement, the method executes synchronously.

In VSPackage I have 2 commands:

```
private void FirstMenuCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThrowElevationRequired();
}

private void SecondMenuCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThrowElevationRequiredAsync();
}
```

Both of this commands force authorization elevation:

```
private void ThrowElevationRequired()
{
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(unchecked((int)0x800702E4));
}

private async void ThrowElevationRequiredAsync()
{
     Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(unchecked((int)0x800702E4));
}
```

The `async` prefix is the only difference for these methods above (no `await` inside, just exception with specific failure HRESULT thrown). Now, I know the asynchronous version has no sense to be here but I'd like to show an issue related with that. Namely, while the first command invoke results in this popup:

[image]

the second command seems to do **nothing**. What is the reason? (Resharper shows the `async` keyword as redundant, which is theoretically true, but as it is shown above, behavior can be very different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the second command seems to do nothing. What is the reason?

The second method is asynchronous, which means exceptions are *never* thrown directly to the caller - whether the exception occurs while the method is executing synchronously or not. An async method which returns a `Task` will make the task "faulted" if the method throws an exception... but when the async method is `void` (which should almost never be the case) it call [`AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.SetException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncvoidmethodbuilder.setexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - the behaviour of which will depend on the synchronization context.

The `async` modifier is definitely not redundant in that it *does* affect behaviour, as you've noted - and that's the correct behaviour, working as designed... it's just that when an `async void` method throws an exception, there's the natural question of what should catch it.

Comment: One correction, The second method isn't asynchronous, it just marked as `async`.

Comment: @Hamlet: It's an asynchronous method as far as the language specification uses the term. I see your point, but I think it's clear enough already.